# Issue with decaying performance on Linux Javafx8 graphics

Tags: java, linux, opengl

[image: test program output]

I've found several hits on here regarding graphics performance in Javafx8 both on Windows and Linux, with certain apps. I've tried a suggestion of -Dprism.vsync=false and that does not seem to effect results. What I did to eliminate an possibility of it being my code is to write a bare bones air-gappable application that just feeds a GraphicsContext2D with a width's worth of data of random heights between 0 and height of the canvas. While I've let it run overnight I will attempt to display the decaying metod invocation time of each graph cycle which is"

This does work better, but not perfect on Windows. The Linux environment is Ubuntu 14.04 current. The Java is 1.8.0_77.

What I do not know is if this is a Javafx8 issue or a Linux or Linix X.Org issue.

-Dprism.verbose data is:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using java-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 16384
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
Non power of two texture support = true
Maximum number of vertex attributes = 16
Maximum number of uniform vertex components = 16384
Maximum number of uniform fragment components = 16384
Maximum number of varying components = 128
Maximum number of texture units usable in a vertex shader = 16
Maximum number of texture units usable in a fragment shader = 16
Graphics Vendor: X.Org
       Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on AMD OLAND
        Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.9
 vsync: true vpipe: true
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: FillPgram_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureRGB.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Mask_TextureSuper.frag
new alphas
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Texture_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Texture_LinearGradient_PAD.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureFirstPassLCD.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureSecondPassLCD.frag
new alphas
```

At the end of however much time I give it to run, measured in hours or nights, cpu as measured with jconsole or jvisualvm, for the app, never goes about, say, about 23%. CPU reported by top is in excess of 50%. Initially CPU is a6 6% and steadily increases to 23% or so within 10 mins but responsiveness of the system is very good. After an evening or night the entire system is pitifully slugish. Terminating the app lock the entire system for maybe a minute or two. Java heap size throughout is exellent remaining under 50MB. On GC it drops to the 20's. I am currently waiting on a graph I am generating with X axis in frames where I generate a new frame every 100ms. One can see the slugishness in the display, being visually much slower but I don't know if generation time differs.The Y axis is in uSec as milliseconds proved too course.  I have become aware of two things:
1) Java9 features a new Marlin renderer
2) Ubuntu 16.04 features new video drivers, AMD in this case, and I believe there are improvements in the kernel as well as relates to graphic performance. As jvisualvm doesn't do lambda expressions I did do a heap dump and look at it offline and saw nothing especially noteworthy there. I do not believe the source of the slow down in in my app. I do notice Xorg is running at about 50% +/- and has a virt footprint around 652K (652232)

In the full app not only is there a oscilloscope type display on top but a waterfall (heat map) below. I can reproduce the system degradation with either one alone but I wanted to get an app small enough to reproduce what I am seeing without extraneous application code confusing the issue. Again, the setting of vsync does not appear to have any effect.

Right now according to top, its saying the java process is using 90% cpu while jvirtualvm is saying the process is using 22-23%, still high considering it started at 6%.

This morning (since I finished writing this last night) the system was completely locked, with interrupts disabled (no num lock or caps lock).

At 3.5 hours in I see, from top, a cpu for java being just shy of 100% and the cpu for XOrg growing slowly. It is now at 42%. The heap in my test app bottoms out at about 13MB. I don't know why it grows from 6% to 23% (according to visualvm yet rises to about 100% according to top. However visualvm shows the cpu and heap flat. [image]
Any observations, suggestions, knowledge of what may be wrong on my end or cures in the pipeline already, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Walt

This drives the display

```
ByteBuffer intBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
while (PanadapterView.running) {
    short height = spectrumView.getController().getHeight();
    short width = spectrumView.getController().getWidth();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        if (height * width != 0) {
            short data[] = new short[width];
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                data[i] = (short)(height - (Math.random()* height));
            }
            milliStart = System.nanoTime();
            controller.onSpectrumDataReady(null, data);
            milliDuration = (int)(System.nanoTime()-milliStart);
            milliDuration += 500;
            milliDuration /=1000;
            intBuffer.asIntBuffer().put(milliDuration);
            if (output != null) {
                int written = output.write(intBuffer);
            }
            intBuffer.clear();
            if (cnt++ % 5000 == 0) {
                if (output != null) {
                    output.force(false);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
        PanadapterView.running = false;
    }
}
if (output != null) {
    output.close();
}
```

}

This draws the canvas

```
    public void onSpectrumDataReady(Panadapter targetPan, short[] data) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            int start = 0;
            double offset = spectrum.getHeight();
            double canvasWidth = spectrum.getWidth();
            double canvasHeight = spectrum.getHeight();
            assert (data.length == canvasWidth);
            GraphicsContext gc = spectrum.getGraphicsContext2D();
            gc.beginPath();
            gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
//            gc.save();
            gc.setLineWidth(1);
            gc.setStroke(Color.WHITESMOKE);
            gc.moveTo(start, (double) data[0]);
            for (int i = start; i < data.length; i++) {
                gc.lineTo((double) i, (double) data[i]);
            }
            gc.stroke();
//            gc.closePath();
        });
    }
```

I just stopped the app. Once I did Xorg cpu dropped to .3%. Here is the graph, the Y axis is wall clock time in uS.[image]

After running for 7 1/2 hrs the following represents the wall clock duration to draw an entire frame. I should point out the following represents a 1min rolling average of method duration.[image: overnight execution]

I did run the identical test overnight on Windows 7 and it had no visible degrdation in drawing and this was scaling back to prism.order=sw, as es2 and es1 were not chosen. The issue appears to be unique to Linux and is either in the JavaFX8 renderer or in xorg itself. Which, this morning was running at 76% cpu.

Comment: I've been doing what I can to research this. Here's what I've found to date. The issue appears to be relegated to the com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline as when specifying sw first in the order the cpu time is solidly at 6% and remains there over a 12 hr period. vsync=false has no effect. Running on Ubuntu 16.04 has no effect although it does run better. What happens is after a couple of hours cpu time goes to 23+% and the graphics are visibly degraded update-wise. Who is doing  sustaining on Javafx8 as I have a very smaill app aitgappable that can easily reproduce the issue.